# ActivityMapsBinding doesn't work, it doesn't let me import the class - Cannot resolve symbol 'ActivityMapsBinding'

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am trying to get google maps to work in my app the moment I deafult google maps via android studio it comes out in red ActivityMapsBinding and then it doesn't work as I should? I've already put addictions and things like that but it doesn't work

```
public class TrovamicoActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private ActivityMapsBinding binding;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    binding = ActivityMapsBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
```

Comment: can you please share your code

Comment: wrap the XML of the activity you want to call in its outermost layer with <layout>

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'ActivityMapsBinding' this error appear

Comment: TrovamicoActivity's xml fair name is Activity_maps.xml ?

Comment: Yes is the google maps

Comment: bro, there is no such thing as ActivityMapsBinding of course because you don't have an xml file called activity_maps

Comment: I edited my code, can you take a look and give it a try?

Answer (score 0):

```
<layout>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".TrovamicoActivity">
             
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

TrovamicoActivity.java

```
private FragmentsTrovamicoBinding binding;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    binding = FragmentsTrovamicoBinding .inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());


}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244283/discussion-on-answer-by-omer-seyfettin-yavuzyigit-activitymapsbinding-doesnt-wo).

Answer (score 0):

There are few things you can do to solve this error,

**First**

Make sure there are buildFeatures added in build.gradle(module:), if not then add like this,

```
buildFeatures {
     viewBinding true 
     dataBinding true
}
```

Then sync. And after that rebuild your project and wait for a while.

**Second**

Invalidate caches & restart then rebuild your project and wait for a while.

**Third**

It might seem a little weird but if you had made any changes in your activity file, undo those changes, come back to your code file, the error will be gone then go back to xml and redo the changes. Error will not show again. (Yeah, I know, Android Studio works in mysterious ways. XD)

**Fourth**

Make sure your activity's xml file is named activity_maps. If it is named maps_actitviy then binding file will be MapsActivityBinding.

These are the solutions I myself go for whenever I face such issue in my code.

If none of them works then just recreate the whole project.

Comment: You don't have any activity named activity_maps, there are just activity_main and fragments_trovamico. and your fragment has the map container.
So, you should be calling for. FragmentTrovamicoBinding, instead of ActivityMapsBinding.