# Unable start activity, FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Tags: java, android

How can I solve this type of problem? The problem is in setOnClickListener which gives me a NullPointerException. If you need anything else let me know.

This is the error in Log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mapsprova/com.example.home.HomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.cardview.widget.CardView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.cardview.widget.CardView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

```java
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private CardView btn_home;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_home);

        btn_home = findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.home);

        btn_home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, TrovamicoActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });

    }
```

Comment: I think your problem comes from context (first param of your Intent), could you please add some log ?

Comment: i have edited now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem originate from your ClickListener, here is the problem :

```java
btn_home = findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.home); // This is wrong
// I believe you have to call it this way (only if its id is 'home' in your layout)
btn_home = findViewById(R.id.home);

// This call fail with NullPointerException
btn_home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    // Listener code
});
```

> Disclaimer : without your layouts I can't tell you for sure what is in cause, but stacktrace is pretty clear, clicklistener cannot be called on null value

## Edit

First, you don't have any View with id 'home' as declared in your mainActivity. So I suppose (as your code confirms, var is a CardView) you intended to use cardview as (sort of) a button. So you have to replace by this code :

```
btn_home = findViewById(R.id.trovamico);
```

Now it should work when you click on your Trovamico Cardview (from HomeActivity

Comment: I checked and you don't even have any layouts with id home. I'll update my answer

Comment: If it's really the case we have to report

Comment: I can show you proof

Comment: Anyway, problem is fixed now

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72016632/activitymapsbinding-doesnt-work-it-doesnt-let-me-import-the-class-cannot-re/72017334?noredirect=1#comment127294838_72017334

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244299/discussion-between-jacouille-and-omer-seyfettin-yavuzyigit).